# Return values of subdocument in Meteor MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform, chained-select

Have the following MongoDB collection:

```
{
    "_id": "u3Yv2bm4cpsssLSHv",
    "allowed": 1,
    "country_name": "Canada",
    "states": [
        {
            "state_name": "Alberta"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "British Columbia"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Manitoba"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "New Brunswick"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Newfoundland and Labrador"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Nova Scotia"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Ontario"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Prince Edward Island"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Quebec"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Saskatchewan"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Northwest Territories"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Nunavut"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "Yukon"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I return the values of the "states" in this collection, so I can populate a dropdown? I am trying to do something as follows (does not return anything in the "states" subdocument"):

```
venue_province: {
    type: String,
    label: "Province/State",
    optional: true,
    max: 200,
    autoform: {
        type: 'chained',
        // Gets a list of province/state names from the locations collection
        options: function() {
            return _.map(bt_col_locations.find().fetch(), function(item) {
                return {value: item.states.state_name, label: item.states.state_name, parent: item.country_name}
            })
        }
    }
```

Note that I am using Aldeed:Autoforms and jQuery Chained; basically I have a parent dropdown for the user to select the country, and the child dropdown cascades with the appropriate states/provinces.

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking. What isn't working? Also, `item.states` is an array so `item.states.state_name` clearly can't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are looking for is probably the Mongo Aggregation framework. (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) I haven't tested your specific usage here, but with that you should be able to use $unwind to get the states array into a more workable state and then just query that. From there you can also do a few other useful operations, like sorting, to make you list look nice.